# Duplicate Windows Services

Tags: .net, windows, web-services, service

I'm facing a problem which I'm not able to resolve. 
 I have created a windows service (dotnet) which performs some action and in case some error occurs, the service stops and need to be restarted.
 I've deployed this service again (duplicate one) with a different name (these two are using different databases).
 When I start the second/ duplicate windows service and it encounters any error it instead of stopping, stops the original windows service that is pointing to a different db.
 I've used SC CREATE to deploy the second service.
 Please suggest if I'm missing something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you actually changed the Service name and not the Display name of the service.  You can verify these are different in the properties of each service in the Services MMC.

It sounds like these are in fact the same service and the original instance is simply getting triggered since both carry the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right and this was indeed the case here. I checked the code and the Windows service name was being hardcoded there.